# Tomcat 8 cannot find my keystore for enabling https

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, keytool

I am trying to enable HTTPS on my local stand-alone tomcat 8.5.20.  Ive seen various questions about the error, but none of them seemed to help

These are the steps I took :
1) "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore C:\tomcat\conf\mykeystore.jks
   Enter keystore password ABCDEF
   .
   .
   Enter key password for  ( pressed return )

Note that I do not do an openSSL prior to this step...

2) "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\tomcat\conf\mykeystore.jks -destkeystore C:\tomcat\conf\mykeystore.jks -
deststoretype pkcs12

3) Add the following to server.xml ( the initial commented out SSL had certificateKeystoreFile but when i looked at apache, they did not list that as an option ive also removed the keystorePass since that wasnt in the original ):

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" >
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate keystoreFile="conf/mykeystore.jks" keystorePass="ABCDEF"
                     type="RSA"/>
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

4) Restarted tomcat.

5) In chrome typed in "https://localhost:8443/myapp" and it just times out.

6) In the catalina.log i get :
     Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]

I also edited the starting parameters for tomcat and added

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:\tomcat\conf\mykeystore.jks

even https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html looks different then what is in my server.xml

Comment: There are significative differences between version 8.0 and 8.5 that you're using , see : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: Follow the documentation above, remove the SSLHostConfig tag.

Comment: Hm.  Cut&Pasted from the 8-05 doc ( thanks for pointing that out ) and changed the keystoreFile to conf/mykeystore.jks but that didnt work.  if i just do "conf/mykeystore.jks" it will look under tomcat's root correct?

Comment: Yes, unless you changed TOMCAT_BASE variable in catalina.bat or setenv.bat

Comment: Ok thanks.  Finally managed it to "accept" the connection.  I was having a brain freeze until i realized i needed to change the password to the password of my keystore :(  For some reason i thought that there were odd reasons for always having password be "changeit", i would have expected <> or [] or {} to denote my info )

Comment: now on to the next ssl issue

Comment: what next issue ? Remove the properties you gave in 6., you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

Create folder in webapps that its name is 8443 and rename war file to root.war and paste war file.
then edit server.xml:

```
<Service name="Catalina8443">
      <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"  clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="conf/certificate.jks" keystorePass="password"
               />
      <Engine name="Catalina8443" defaultHost="localhost">
          <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

          <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps/8443"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

          </Host>
      </Engine>
</Service>
```